# JSF2 Spring3 integration

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2

```
@ManagedBean(name="helloBean")
@SessionScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    @Named("loginService")
    LoginService loginService;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name+"-->"+loginService.serviceDetails();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

...

```
    @Named("loginService")
    public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService {

        public String serviceDetails() {
            return "==From Service==";
        }
    }
```

ApplicationContext.xml file:

```
<beans
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp"/>
</beans>
```

I am getting null pointer exception for loginService  at return 
`name+"-->"+loginService.serviceDetails();`

1) How can I solve above problem

2) instead of `@ManagedBean(name="helloBean")` can I use `@Inject`? how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use `@ManagedBean` and and spring at the same time. If you want your beans to be managed by spring, you need to use the [spring `ELResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#jsf-springbeanfaceselresolver) (in faces-config.xml) and then use `@Named` and `@Scope("session")` on the JSF beans as well. Then you can (and must) use `@Inject` rather than `@ManagedX`

And as a sidenote - avoid referring to non-jsf beans by name - rely on their type only - it will save you headaches with refactoring, at least. And for the JSF beans you can rely on the default naming and use `@Named` without arguments.

Comment: only specifying ELResolver is sufficient in faces-config.xml? or do i need to specify Managed bean name,class and scope also?

Comment: only the el-resolver. The rest is obtained from the annotations on the bean

Comment: then is there anyway i can include these el-resolver in spring ApplicationContext.xml file instead of faces-config.xml? so that one single xml file for whole application.

Comment: no. You have to tell JSF how to resolve its beans. But that's the only thing that's required in the faces-context.xml

Comment: ok finally solved with(JSR 330) @Named("helloBean") and @Scope("request") with faces-config.xml for EL-Resolver.